# Fixed points of linear transformation and commutativity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true the statement that

***if*** two square matrices $A$ i $B$ have the same fixed points $≠0$ for their linear transformation (i.e. for some vectors $v_i ≠0 $ we have $Av_i=v_i$ and $ Bv_i=v_i$) **then** they are commutative (and their product has the same fixed points - what is easy to prove).

If not when information about fixed points can be used to confirm commutativity ?

Examples:
rotations in 3D about the same axis **or** composition of rotation and projection onto rotation axis.

*Is it true also the linked statement that

**if** two matrices $A$ and $B$ are commutative and have some fixed points $≠0$ common **then** all their fixed points $≠0$ must be the same?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

For the first question consider the counterexample:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\0&2
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad 
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\0&-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that have the same eigenvector $v=[1,0]^T$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$, but have the second eigenvalue and eigenvector different. The two matrices does not commute.

For the second a counterexample is simpler:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad 
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Ok, I see ( in your example the first row of A is the same as in B and the second  row of B is minus second row of A - has it a meaning?). But why my examples are commutative ? Fixed points give nothing?

Comment: For the second example - what if we exclude from the statement identity matrix? ( identity matrix has all space of fixed points so if the other matrix has some they have to be common)

Comment: The point is that If two matrices commute they are simultaneously triangularizable.
I've chosen a simple numerical example, but you can use any two upper triangular matrices that have a common eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ a common eigenvector for such eigenvalue, but different aigenvectors for the oter eigenvalues, so that they are not simultaneously triangularizable.

Comment: Hmm, rotations about the same axis in 3D commute  - are they  simultaneously triangularizable?

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices#Characterization_in_terms_of_eigenvectors

Comment: Ok, I see. But is there any connection between fixed points and commutativity or rather not ?

Comment: I don't know any simple connection.

Comment: And what about my examples? They have common fixed points but commutativity  property arises probably, I have to accept it now, somehow differently.